# Is there an algorithm to return the second largest element in a stack in constant time?

Tags: algorithm, stack

I am aware of how to do this  for the largest element in stack using an auxiliary stack that stores the maximums. Wondering if this can be extended to return both max and second max in constant time.

Comment: Yes, just use the same technique.

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if I pop out the max element?

Comment: Sure - but you can just push it back in afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing the largest element on the auxiliary stack, you put (largest, second_largest) pairs.  Or you could push them onto two parallel stacks.

Pseudocode:

```
int largest = second_largest = MIN_INT;

push(int x)
{
    stack1.push(x);
    stack2.push(largest);
    stack3.push(second_largest);

    if (x >= largest)
    {
        second_largest = largest;
        largest = x;
    }
    else if (x > second_largest)
    {
        second_largest = x;
    }
}

int pop()
{
   second_largest = stack3.pop();
   largest = stack2.pop();
   return stack1.pop();
}
```

The pattern is an *undo stack*.  Whenever `push()` makes changes to things you're keeping track of, then you save enough information to *undo* those changes when you get a `pop()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create second auxiliary stack for second maximum. Here is example of the minimum and second minimum auxiliary stacks idea after inserting some numbers:

```
Actual Stack
16 <--- top     
15
29
19 
18
Auxiliary Stack
15 <---- top
15
18
18
18
Second Auxiliary Stack
18 <---- top
18
N/A
N/A
N/A
```

I'm afraid that there is no other solution for getting second maximum in case of auxiliary stacks with O(1) time complexity.

**EDIT - explenation**

```
putting i:
- put i to main stack
- if i is smaller than top of 1st auxiliary stack, put it there, if it is not
  put the same number.
- if top of 1st auxiliary stack changed, put previous 1st auxiliary top to 2nd 
  auxiliary stack. If it is not just put the same number as it was to the top.

popping is just popping from each stack.
```

Comment: You don't need a second auxiliary stack, the original auxiliary stack is sufficient.

Comment: If You have constant access to the innner elements of stack. And there is no assumption that You are in case of stacks. For example with linked list implementation. Or You have to iterate through stack which is time consuming. O(n) pessimistically.

Comment: There is no need to iterate.  Just pop off the max, then peeking will reveal the second max.

Comment: @Piotr, thanks for the reply! Could you please explain your example a bit if you don't mind? Shouldn't the second maximum be 19?

Comment: And that method consumes O(n) time pessimistically. Consider auxiliary stack like this: `5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 8`

Comment: @wishywashy my bad, my example is about minimum and second minimum. But idea for maximum is the same. N/A means that there is no second minimum.

Comment: i edited answer and added some explenation of algorithm.

Comment: How can there not be a second (smallest) element after the second push? The stack at that point contains 18, 19; the smallest element is 18 and the second smallest is 19. I think the algorithm fails if the element pushed on to the main stack is ever the second smallest (largest in the OP) element. And I think that flaw applies to @OliverCharlesworth's proposal as well, unless there is more to it than appears to be the case.

Comment: This method doesn't work.  After seeing [5,1,2], 2 is the second-smallest, but isn't on any stack

Comment: @rici - yes, you're right, what I'm proposing also wouldn't work in that case.